# How recover deleted crontab (-r option)

Tags: linux, cron

I have deleted my `crontab` using `crontab -r` command (`r` and `e` are so close on keyboard and there wasn't question sort of `Are you sure? [Y/n]`.

Its funny, you must use `-i` option to enable this question - should be enabled by default :-)

My `crontab` records are definitely lost or there is some backup file, how can I recover it ?

Thank you.

Comment: ive listed log file with "grep CRON /var/log/syslog" and recovered my crontab records using informations in it ... it was not easy, but its possible sollution.

Comment: Interesting to read: [Recover cron jobs accidently removed with crontab -r](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136352/40596). That's a very bad implementation, I agree there should be a y/n confirmation prompt.

Comment: That's why I keep my crontab in a file in a version control system.

Comment: Duplicate. I answered this here already https://serverfault.com/a/377204/48782

Comment: I'm on this nightmare right now!! It's umbelievable such bizarre implementation of the crontab command parameters!! Surreal!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue but I had edited the crontab file several times before pressing crontab -r, so I could find the previous versions in tmp directory. So try your luck looking into your tmp directory once.

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky and this happend fairly recent, you might find it in

`/tmp/crontab.<unique_identifier>/crontab`

This is a copy of your previous crontab. You can simply copy and paste it to get your cronjobs back

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the crontab mechanism does not provide a way to recover deleted or earlier versions of your crontab file. That being said, it is always worth tracing the following steps:

1. **Check lingering temporaries:**
   When you edit a crontab file, you make use of an editor. By default, this is `vi`, but it could also be the one defined by the variables `EDITOR` or `VISUAL`. Depending on the settings of those editors and your handling, you might have lingering backup files laying around. These could be of the form `filename~` or `#filename` or anything else. Check files that could represent backups of `_PATH_TMP/crontab.XXXXXXX`. The value of `_PATH_TMP` is defined in `/usr/include/paths.h`. If that file does not exist, it defaults to `/tmp`. Be aware that `/tmp` is wiped at every reboot of your system.
2. **Check filesystem snapshots or clones:** Crontab stores user crontab files in an implementation-dependent location. By default this is `/var/cron/tabs/$USER` but it could also be `/var/spool/cron/$USER` or anything else. Check `man crontab` to disclose the location. There will never be a backup file there. However, your system might have a filesystem that has snapshots or clones configured. These are read-only copies of the filesystem taken at a moment in time. Think of it as a backup on the file system itself.   From the more classic filesystems (ext4, ...) BTRFS, OCFS2 and ZFS support snapshots.
3. **Check actual backups:** Maybe you are in luck and your system-administrator made backups for you.

Beyond these 3 possibilities, I do not see a way how you could recover your crontab.

The most important thing you should do is to let cron backup your crontab file. You could do this hourly using:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .----------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *   command to be executed
  0  *  *  *  *   crontab -l > tmp/crontab.bck
```

Obviously, you can make it more intelligent with a script, but this would already satisfy your bare needs.